# Removing subtitle on "Add New Keyboard..." screen for third-party keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

How do I remove the "3" in the below? Not sure where it is coming form - tried editing the "Bundle display name" in the "Info.plist" file in both the containing app and target extension.

[image]

Tried editing the Info.plist file in the target, but didn't seem to be anything wrong there:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let change your Bundle identifier to onother one. On Xcode, Project -> Targets -> "your product" -> Identity -> Bundle Identifier. May be short one is better, please try it :)

Comment: That seemed to work! I had a "-3" after my Bundle Identifier name...no clue why Xcode interpreted that the way it did.

Comment: Hi, I am also trying to remove the subtitle, but after changing the bundle Identifier, it will not build to simulator, message: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0."  I tried clean build and reset, but no change.

Comment: Got it to work, in my case, after changing the container App bundle ID, it did not match the first part of the Extension keyboard bundle ID.  Both IDs had to be changed to match before it will run in Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally edited your keyboard's `info.plist` (contained in the `Supporting Files` folder of the keyboard target -- there will be one for your container app as well, in the container target) file to have '3' as the primary language of your keyboard extension. You should check the value of the `PrimaryLanguage` key in the `NSExtensionAttributes` dictionary.

You can check the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html) for more details, and for the appropriate values to replace '3' with.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to help.  Added a photo of what those attributes look like for me - PrimaryLanguage is "en-US"

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i am running into the same thing and yeah, that particular 2nd line on the "Add New Keyboard" screen is nowhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue. Our bundle name is something like com.awesome-more. We had the subtitle more for version 9.x but in 10.x it was fixed. This was on the add new keyboard screen only!